# Increasing the number of instant results in a Lookup field

Tags: lookup-filter, lookup-field

I have a lookup field in my Contact records that lets you choose a shipping address that is related to the Contact's Account.I applied a filter to this lookup field so it only displays addresses that are related to the Contact's Account record so you don't have to type anything into the lookup field, you can just click on it and select one of the instant results.

Here is an example of the issue I'm having:

If an Account record has 10 related addresses, the lookup field in the Contact record only displays a maximum of 5 instant results, which causes you to have to type in the Account ID to show all of the address records for that account. This obviously defeats the purpose of the lookup filter.

Is there any way to increase the number of instant results that are displayed for a lookup field?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no settings that allow to fiddle lookups the way you want.

Comment: Is there any way of accomplishing this using Apex?